# Can I export a Windows CRITICAL_SECTION from a DLL?

Tags: c++, dllexport, critical-section

I hovered over `CRITICAL_SECTION` in VSCode and the tooltip reads:

```
typedef RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION CRITICAL_SECTION 
typedef struct __unnamed_struct_13a13_1 CRITICAL_SECTION
```

I am not sure how exporting structs work.  Can I do this?

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) CRITICAL_SECTION myCritSect;
```

Comment: I assume you have to do that, but it does not look like a good synchronization pattern. Mutexes should be private to some objects, and acquired for very limited scope -- not across modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why it should not work, but I would rather use a pointer to critical section returned by a function. That must definitely work.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPCRITICAL_SECTION GetProtector();
```